# Opencv java - Detect numbers with cascade classifiers

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0, cascade-classifier

I have created nine classifiers (numbers 1-9) using the opencv_traincascade utility. Now I want to use them to detect some numbers, the problem is: when I pass an image with a number, more than one classifier detect his number (e.g. numbers 1 and 7 because they look similar), so is there a way to find out the best matching?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: You don't need code. I just have nine CascadeClassifier trained with number images. I only want to know if there is a method to find out the best matching among these classifiers.

Comment: OpenCv is  written in C++ and you have tagged this question in Java, how are you calling opencv functions, are you using a library like JavaCV

Comment: OpenCV supports Java since 2013...

Comment: Sorry I was a bit outdated on that !

Comment: you are abusing an object*detection* mechanism for a *classification* problem. this won't work.